# JavaFX canvas element id (styling canvas elements via CSS)

Tags: css, javafx

Using JavaFX2 and Scene Builder (and new to all this), I have a border layout with a canvas. I obtain a GraphicsContext and draw a rectangle using gc.strokeRect(). Works fine.
Now I want to style that rectangle using css. But the missing link for me is that there seems to be no way of setting an id for a given canvas element. So in my css I'm lost as to how to refer to the rectangle. All examples I have Googled such as canvas.getChildren, rect.setId etc. don't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) elements using CSS.

CSS is for styling scene graph nodes not Canvas elements.

If you want to style a Rectangle via CSS, then don't use a Canvas, instead create a [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) and place the rectangle in a parent scene graph node such as a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) which is attached to a Scene.

- Read the Oracle tutorial on [Working with the JavaFX Scene Graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm#JFXSG107) to get your rectangle into the scene.
- Then take a look at the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape) to understand the JavaFX CSS styling capabilities for rectangles.